# Calculate available timeslots

Tags: php, php-carbon

I have the following script which displays available timeslots:

```
$businessHours = [
    ['09:00:00', '13:00:00'],
    ['14:00:00', '18:00:00'] // notice the 1 hour break
];

$appointments = [
    ['10:00:00', '10:30:00'], // format is [from, until]
    ['15:30:00', '16:10:00']
];

$result = [];
foreach ($businessHours as $businessHour) {
    list($start, $end) = [strtotime($businessHour[0]), strtotime($businessHour[1])];

    while ($start < $end) {
        $first = $start;
        $start += 15 * 60; // this is the interval, equals 15 minutes, will be dynamic based on service duration

        $result[] = [date('H:i:s', $first), date('H:i:s', $start)];
    }
}

foreach ($appointments as $appointment) {

    foreach ($result as $k => $item) {
        if (strtotime($item[0]) >= strtotime($appointment[0]) &&  strtotime($item[1]) <= strtotime($appointment[1])){
            unset($result[$k]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

It works correct when using times like `16:00`, `16:15`, `16:30`, `16:45` etc.

But whenever there is a time like `16:10`, `16:20`, `16:40`, it returns incorrect available timeslots.

How to solve this? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Need more information, you're running through 15 minutes intervals and wondering why 10/20/40 minute intervals aren't included?

Comment: Hey @MarkOverton, the interval could be anything, it's based on which service is selected by the end user. It will be a variable later on.

Comment: _Which_ interval are you talking about - the business hours, or the appointments? Or both?

Comment: In general, you have an "overlap" of intervals, if the start time of your appointment falls between the start and end time of your business hour interval, or if the end time of your appointment falls between the start and end time of your business hour interval. You are currently only checking start >= start and end <= end.